# Партиционирование MySQL таблицы, как временное решение?

Tags: mysql, innodb

В проекте есть пара таблиц, в которые по предположению, будет вестись активная запись. По моим расчетам она будет разбухать от 1-го до 4-х гигабайт в месяц. Чтение будет производиться крайне редко и в основном за текущий месяц.

Правильным ли будет применить партиции? 
Планирую разбить помесячно, а идея с мерджем что-то совсем не нравиться. Или посоветуйте свой вариант. Благодарю.

P.S. Архивировать планирую, все старше полугода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB убрать - оно заточено под связи между таблицами и обеспечение ссылочной целостности. Если данные льются в базу и практически не читаются, то лучше MyISAM, еще лучше - Archive. Индексы тут ни к чему. Партиции тоже - они нужны для таблиц, данные из которых постоянно читаются.

Здесь же: подумайте над возможностью фиксировать изменения при помощи триггеров в дополнительных таблицах, которые уже можно будет заточить под чтение. Вообще повод посмотреть в сторону связки [OLTP+OLAP](http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html).

Второе. Подумать все-таки над вариантом создавать через некоторый промежуток времени новую таблицу. Например, раз в три-шесть месяцев. 4 гигабайта не очень много. Так что не привязывайтесь к месяцу.

Третье. Посмотрите в сторону MongoDB.